# Real-time controlled pop up box message on PHP

Tags: php, javascript, json

I am developing a small real-time project where i am looking for something to send real-time announcements / pop up messages (that i can control) to push Admin controlled messages to all users on the web page.

i came across something on the internet called [Realtime announcer](http://codecanyon.net/item/realtime-announcements-bar-no-reloading-required/300845) but due to company policy, code has to be written by our self.

now what i did i created a table on the DB "CTrealtimeUpdates" that will hold the updates and on the .php page i want to create something that will activate a javascript pop up box with the echoed message from the DB only when the table is updated with any news on the last 10 seconds (this is for active users on the page already) and on the last 5 minutes for any one who have just visited the page.

DB Table :

Date:
Time:
Announcement:
Announcer:

all i created is the table and i am stuck with what code should i do on the page.

Appreciate your assistance please.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this :
[How to implement COMET with PHP](http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start)

Comment: Hmm, doesn't the server time out PHP scripts that never returns?

Comment: Even if there is a timeout, the Js code given in this article allows you to resend a request to the server.

Comment: Thank you ! . its live now :)

Answer (score 1):

PHP can not push anything to the client.
What you would do is to setup a javascript that run periodically to check if there is any anouncement to show.

//jk